# Angular 2 : Auto data refresh on app when changes in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysqli, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I'm working on an angular 2 web app, fetching the data from the MySQL database using php and display on the browser. But when I modify the data from the database, the changes are not automatically reflected in the browser.

I have to refresh the page manually to see changes.

So, how can I reflect those changes without manually refreshing the page?

Comment: Do you use any function to modify (send data to database) in your page?

Comment: no... I have manually edited the values

Comment: You have to push changes from the database / server to the browser, or the browser must regularly pull data / check for updates.

Comment: You will have to use push notifications or something to force refresh on browser, can be solved via service worker